# C# Entity Framework insert relationship tables?

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, entity

I want to insert data three relation table but I can't do this :/

here is the code

```
hali_sahaEntities con = new hali_sahaEntities();
Users user = new Users();
            Emails email = new Emails();
            Phones phone = new Phones();
        user.Name = textBox1.Text;
        user.Surname = textBox7.Text;
        user.IdentityNumber = Convert.ToInt32( textBox2.Text);
        user.Adress = textBox5.Text;
        user.Comment = textBox6.Text;
        email.TCKN = Convert.ToInt32( textBox2.Text);
        email.Email = textBox4.Text;
        phone.TCKN = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        phone.Phone = textBox3.Text;
        con.Users.Add(user);
            con.Emails.Add(email);
            con.Phones.Add(phone);
            con.SaveChanges();
```

I can insert data Users Table but Emails and Phones tables can not insert data?

here my tables[image]

[image: I changed my database like this]

Comment: how relationship between tables? one to one?

Comment: I use one to many

Comment: do you create  relationship in your entity model?

Comment: Yes ı added bottom page

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will be gave this error

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Emails_Users". The conflict occurred in database "****", table "dbo.Users", column 'IdentityNumber'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

so you can fix it by this change:

```
con.Users.Add(user);
con.SaveChanges();//*Because of the relationship*
con.Emails.Add(email);
con.Phones.Add(phone);
con.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @oEs please copy your stack trace and inner exceptions here

Answer (score 0):

I changed my database like this
[image]

Comment: is this your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
hali_sahaEntities con = new hali_sahaEntities();
     Users user = new Users();

        user.Name = textBox1.Text;
        user.Surname = textBox7.Text;
        user.IdentityNumber = Convert.ToInt32( textBox2.Text);
        user.Adress = textBox5.Text;
        user.Comment = textBox6.Text;

        Emails email = new Emails();      
        email.TCKN = Convert.ToInt32( textBox2.Text);
        email.Email = textBox4.Text;
        user.Emails.Add(email);//Emails is virtual proparty

        Phones phone = new Phones();
        phone.TCKN = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        phone.Phone = textBox3.Text; 
        user.Phones.Add(phone);//Phones is virtual proparty

        con.Users.Add(user);
        con.SaveChanges();
```